# SQLException was unhandled by user code in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I try to check user is exist or not.I try:

```
public static bool GetUser(string tblName, string UserName,string Password,string Usertype)
        {
            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                       cmd.CommandText = "select count(UserName) from " + tblName + " where Password=" + Password + " and usertype=" + Usertype + " and username="+ UserName + "";
                        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (obj != null)
                            return true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

When I call this method I got a following error.
[image: My Error]
connection is successfully established and I call this method like this.

```
bool Check = UserLogin.GetUser("OnlineCertificationLogin", "admin", "admin", "Admin");
```

My table structure is

[image: My Table Structure]
Unable to find my mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not quoting the values, so your SQL ends up as:

```
select count(UserName) from OnlineCertificationLogin
where Password=admin and usertype=admin and username=Admin
```

**Don't** fix this by adding quotes. Your code would then *work* for the sample given, but you'd be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Instead, you should fix this using a parameterized query - see [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information and an example.

Although you can't parameterize the table name, you should make sure that it only *ever* comes via trusted code - not via user input, for example, as otherwise you've got exactly the same SQL injection problem again.

Note that you *also* shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text like that.

I strongly recommend that you get hold of a book on security - [Beginning ASP.NET Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470743654) might be up your street. (I have a copy but I confess haven't read it much - I've listened to Barry talking about security though, and he explains it all very clearly.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's all about string values *injection* into the final `SQL query`.

Do not use *simple string concatentaion*, but use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to inject the values into the query and most probably your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta escape your parameters,

Moreover, you shouldn't use direct SQL commands like that, you should use [SQL parameterization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

```
            using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT count(UserName) FROM" + tblName +
                    " WHERE Password=@pPass AND usertype=@pUsertype AND
                    username=@pUsername";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pPass", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pUsertype", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["pUsername"] = UserName;
                    cmd.Parameters["pPass"] = Password;
                    cmd.Parameters["pUsertype"] = Usertype;
                    object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (obj != null)
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(UserName) from " + tblName + " where Password='" + Password + "' and usertype='" + Usertype + "' and username='"+ UserName + "'";
```

Try this, i guess your problem about ' .